# How to configure CodeIgniter to automatically detect development machine and real machine?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing from my Windows laptop but need to test my development on my shared Linux hosting. I have thrown together the following in place of the normal `$application_path = "application";` line.

`$env['laptop']['ip'] = '127.0.0.1';
$env['laptop']['host'] = 'MATT-WINDOWS7';
$env['laptop']['path'] = 'private';`

$env['mattpotts']['ip'] = '12.34.56.78';
$env['mattpotts']['host'] = 'my.webhost.com';
$env['mattpotts']['path'] = '../private/blah';

`$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
 $host = php_uname('n');
 foreach($env as $e)
  if($e['ip'] == $ip && $e['host'] == $host)
   $application_folder = $e['path'];
 unset($env);
 if(!isset($application_folder))
  die('application folder not set');`

...which works fine for setting the application path but now I'm running into trouble with the need for a database config for each environment.

I can make it work with a few simple ifs but I was wondering if there's a best practice solution to this one.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use revision control such as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). Have one configuration file deployed to your test environment and a modified version checked out in your development environment. Simply tell your client to not commit those configuration changes so they don't make it to your testing/production environment.

This is definitely the best practice solution :)

P.S. If you don't feel like setting up a Subversion server, there's always hosted solutions like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) and if you're on Windows, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a slick client.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel like setting up subversion you can always detect what site you're on by looking at `SERVER_NAME`. In a CI site in the past I used the following within my config.php to figure out dev vs production servers:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.mysite.com') {
    $config['log_path'] = '/var/log/site/';
} else {
    $config['log_path'] = '/var/log/dev_site/';
}
```

You can use this anywhere you need to have different variables based on environment. That being said hard-coding stuff like this into your code isn't always the best idea.

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to check by domain? At least laravel frameworks says so:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade
"For security reasons, URL domains may no longer be used to detect your application environment."
Only weird thing is that I only find this in laravel docs, not somewhere else on the internet so far

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice clean solution to running multiple production environments on a single codebase:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/01/How-to-Support-multiple-production-environments-in-CodeIgniter

Comment: After switching from using Zend Framework, where setting the environment is a lot more central to the app, I really need something simple but effective like this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil's solution is no longer accessible, here's another solution that'll provide you with the exact same solution.

Here's the link to the Git repo: https://github.com/jedkirby/ci-multi-environments and this is a brief explanation of the module: http://jedkirby.com/blog/2012/11/codeigniter-multiple-development-environments

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sturgeons page has moved to here:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/01/How-to-Support-multiple-production-environments-in-CodeIgniter